# Angular PrimeIcons work locally but not on IIS

Tags: angular, iis, angular-cli, primeng, primeicons

I'm using primeicons and primeng in my angular app.

If I'm running the angular website/app locally, everything is fine.

But deploying to an IIS server, the icons are not shown - but all other styles are running well.

Is this something in the configuration of the IIS?

**Usage** in code:

```
<i class="pi pi-exclamation-circle">
```

**styles** in the angular.json:

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
              "src/styles.less"                            
            ],
```

**dependencies** in the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.12",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "primeflex": "^1.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^3.0.0",
    "primeng": "^9.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.13.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
```

Comment: what is the the font file extension (eg woff, woff2. ttf etc) and is this allowed by your IIS config ... font files are usually in the root of your build/deply folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add an exception for woff and ttf files in the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="SPA" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(?!.*(\.js|\.css|\.png|\.jpg|\.ico|\.svg|\.ttf|\.woff|\.eot)).*$" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/"  appendQueryString="true" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, missed that :-)